# Boundary points of a convex domain are regular

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I need to show that the each boundary point of a convex domain $\Omega$ is regular where a point $x_0$ on the boundary is said to be regular if there exist a barrier function at $x_0$. And by a barrier function at $x_0$ we mean that a superharmonic function $u$ such that $u>0$ in $\bar{\Omega}\setminus{\{x_0\}}$ and $u(x_0)=0$.

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, each boundary point $z_0$ of a convex set in $\Bbb R^n$ has a [supporting hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) containing $z_0$.
For a convex set  $\Omega \subset \Bbb C$ this means that $\Omega$ is contained in some half-plane $H$ with $z_0 \in \partial H$.

So by translating/rotating $\Omega$ we can assume that it is contained
in the right half-plane and $z_0 = 0$ is the boundary point in question.

Now define $u(z) = \operatorname{Re}(\sqrt z)$ where $\sqrt z$
is the principal branch of the square root which maps the right half-plane onto the sector $\{ -\pi/4 < \arg z < \pi/4 \}$. Then $u$
is harmonic in $\Omega$ with $\lim_{z \to 0} u(z) = 0$
and $\lim_{z \to \zeta} u(z) = u(\zeta) > 0$ for all boundary points
$\zeta \ne 0$.